# Why do I get a segmentation fault when trying to map a string to its tokens?

Tags: c

I need to map string to arrays such that `"hacker"` maps to `[ "h", "ack", "er" ]`. That is, I need to find the largest sets of contiguous characters in a string that are in increasing order.

I have to write a function that takes

- **a string**
- a pointer to **an array of strings**
- a pointer to **the size of the latter**

such that

```
f("hacker") = ([ "h", "ack", "er"], 3)
```

A typical call and use of this function would be

```
char **tokens = NULL;
size_t tokens_length = 0;
tokenize("hacker", &tokens, &tokens_size)
printf("[ ");
for (int i = 0; i < tokens_length; i++) {
    printf("\"%s\", " tokens[i]);
}
printf("]");
```

Here's the body of the function that I wrote

```
void tokenize (const char *s, char ***tokens, size_t *tokens_length) {
    char *current_ptr = NULL;
    char *previous_ptr = NULL;
    size_t characters_read = 0;
    current_ptr = previous_ptr = s;
    for (; current_ptr < s + strlen(s);) {
        characters_read = characters_read + 1;
        if (*(current_ptr + 1) < *current_ptr) {
            *tokens_length = *tokens_length + 1;
            *tokens = (char**)realloc((void*)*tokens, *tokens_length * sizeof(char*));
            *tokens[*tokens_length - 1] = (char*)calloc(characters_read + 1, sizeof(char));
            strncpy(*tokens[*tokens_length - 1], previous_ptr, characters_read * sizeof(char));
            previous_ptr = current_ptr + 1;
            characters_read = 0;
        }
        current_ptr = current_ptr + 1;
    }
}
```

And here's the typical output ...

```
[1]    4789 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Do you have a clue about why I'm failing to manage the memory?

---

[Here](https://gist.github.com/giuscri/2f6a0bfeffbcc1704405) is the source that I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: This is like the hundredth "debug my segmentation fault" problem posted today.  Even if you have no idea what a debugger is, you can still put `printf` statements in your code to narrow it down to the exact line that is causing the crash.  Why don't you do that and then update your question with the line and the values of the variables that you use on that line when it crashes.

Comment: So compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info) use `gdb` (the debugger).

Comment: `*tokens[*tokens_length - 1]` should be `(*tokens)[*tokens_length - 1]` , you have that error in other places too.  To make your code more readable I suggest using a local `char **` that you initialize from `*tokens`; and then at the end of the function copy the value back to `*tokens`

Comment: @giuscri It would be much better if thye function return the num ber of tokens.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, thank you. The error was there! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch!:) At least I did not get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t tokenize( const char *s, char ***tokens )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    const char *p;

    *tokens = NULL;

    p = s;
    while ( *p )
    {
        for ( const char *q = p; !( *++p < *q ); ++q );
        ++n;
    }

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        *tokens = ( char ** )malloc( n * sizeof( char * ) );

        p = s;
        do
        {
            const char *q = p++;

            while ( !( *p < *( p - 1 ) ) ) ++p;

            ( *tokens )[i] = malloc( p - q + 1 );
            strncpy( ( *tokens )[i], q, p - q );
            ( *tokens )[i][p-q] = '\0';

            ++i;
        } while ( *p );
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "hacker";
    char **tokens;
    size_t n;

    n = tokenize( s, &tokens );

    printf( "[ " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\", ", tokens[i] );
    }
    printf( "]\n" );

    free( tokens );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the following

```
[ "h", "ack", "er", ]
```